# Entity Framework 4: In which scenarios do pregenerated views boost performance?

Tags: entity-framework, entity

We have a project where we use Entity Framework 4. I have tested pregenerated views. But we see no performance difference at all. Example: We have a transaction table, with about 20 columns. Will pregenerated views help the first time i run a query like this one:

Transaction transaction = repo.Single(t => t.TransactionId == 22857);

More general, does pregenerated views increace performance in scenarios where the "where" statement differ?

Another strange thing is that if i run in debug, sets breakpoints in the autogenerated ...Views.cs class, the code never enters the autogenerated ...Views.cs class.

Answer (score 1):

Pregenerated views won't help for custom queries like yours. A `CompiledQuery` will help this, though.

They do help for queries generated with, e.g., `myEntity.SomeAssociation.Load()`. Or lazy loading. Or an unrestricted select all.

It only helps for the first execution in a context, but it can be a noticeable improvement.

Comment: static readonly Func<OPContext, int, IQueryable<Transaction>> s_compiledQuery2 = CompiledQuery.Compile<OPContext, int, IQueryable<Transaction>>( (ctx, myId) => from transaction in ctx.Transaction.Include("Debtor.Creditor.Identity") .Include("Debtor.Identity.DefaultPostAddress") where transaction.TransactionId == myId && transaction.IsCustomerTransaction && transaction.IsPosted select transaction);  This query is actually SLOWER when precompiling it. Maybe due to the includes? But how to do this includes so that the precompilation is effective?

Comment: Precompiling gives no benefit on the first execution. Only on the 2nd+.